# IE Website content only show on Browser Visible Area Only

Tags: css, internet-explorer, background, internet-explorer-9

found this great site and this is my first question here.

Currently i m working on a site, it looks good on most of the browser but 2 problems found on some of the browsers.

Here is the page:
http://www.linkmen.com.hk/web2013/20130426/contact.htm

and here is the problem:
http://www.linkmen.com.hk/web2013/20130426/problem.png

problem 1: On some safari machine will display the background like this. it also happened when open firebug on browser or so.

problem 2: I tested on couple window vista with ie 9(new machines), seems the site's content only show on Browser Visible Area Only, when scroll down everything below are gone.

thank you~

Answer (score 0):

move orange background `.orange` class from body, that has `height:100%` to `.container_contact` that has `min-height 100%`

Comment: thank you Vicky, i wil try to put .orange under .container_contact then

Comment: not under,but on, block with orange background should have min-height: 100%